# Using if/else with JS in Appium?

Tags: javascript, testing, conditional-statements, appium

So I'm trying to figure out how to make my `Appium` login test perform different actions based on whether it is a PIN entry or password but I cant seem to get it to work. Is there another way that I can achieve the intended effect or am I just making a dumb syntax mistake?

EDIT: The if/else statement works now I just cant get the right condition

Comment: You cannot access directly '.' you have to execute the methods on an object/instance, like: myObject.isVisible

Comment: Also you have a return in the first line, what's the purpose of that one?

Comment: @A.Llorente To return my emulator/device from what I understand. Oh ok I'll try that and get back to you